# What do you call a person who appears to be oblivious to their ignorance?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What is the appropriate name for a person who exhibits the behavior described below?

A person who speaks in a Confidently informed manner (about a technical process or procedure for example) however they are actually imparting incorrect information and are apparently oblivious of their actions.

Comment: The words you are looking for are *oblivious* and *ignorant*.

Comment: Why do you want a word for a person you disapprove of?

Comment: @tchrist: I see no inherent contradiction in wanting such a word.

Comment: _self deceiver_ could apply here.

Comment: The normal kind -- it's rare to find someone aware of their ignorance -- such a person would be a sage.

Comment: probably nincompoop ?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261574/a-person-unaware-his-confidence-exceeds-his-talent

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178819/someone-who-just-thinks-they-know-what-theyre-talking-about

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259004/what-do-you-call-someone-who-thinks-everyone-is-incompetent-doesnt-know-anythi

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209496/describe-a-fallacious-opinion-regarding-ones-own-ability

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229739/how-to-describe-a-person-in-a-situation-in-which-he-does-not-completely-know-wha

Comment: (I think this question is a dupe.)

Comment: Just to make it clear, the syndrome, as discussed in all the above dupes, is known as the "Dunning-Kruger Effect".

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase *blissful ignorance* that has been in use for centuries. Examples can be found following this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blissful%20ignorance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblissful%20ignorance%3B%2Cc0).

*[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/blissful-ignorance)* defines it as

> Fortunate unawareness of something unpleasant.

As the definition indicates, its application is much broader than erroneous pontification, and the unpleasantness will be felt by the listeners, not the speaker.

*[Bloviate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bloviate)* means

> Talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Again, this is broader, and may include talk that is hollow, but not necessarily erroneous.

Or you might coin your own phrase, such as *master of misinformation*.

Comment: According to this [site](http://www.sunnah.org/fiqh/usul/nature_of_ignorance.htm), the romans used to say "dulcis ignorantia" which is in line with "blissful ignorance" and denotes the concept of compound ignorance.

Answer (score -1):

I personally like the term ***[ignoramus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignoramus)***.

> a person who does not know much : an ignorant or stupid person

Also [called](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignoramus)

> unknowledgeable, uneducated, or uninformed; a fool.

References:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignoramus
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ignoramus

Comment: This word doesn't account for the misplaced confidence aspect.

Comment: If you are very ignorant you do not know what you lack, unfortunately. Oxford: 'assume that your examiner is an ignoramus and explain everything to him'